# Difference between (\w)* and \w?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to study regexes, and I came upon this confusing scenario:

Suppose you have the text:

> hello world

If you run the regex (\w)*, it gives:

> ['hello', 'o']

What I expected was:

> ['hello', 'h']

Doesn't \w mean any word character?

**Another example**:

Text:

> Delicious cake

(\w)* output:

> ['Delicious', 's']

What I expected:

> ['Delicious', 'D']

Comment: Could you please show us more details? Exact regexps, exact input and results could be useful for example.

Comment: `(\w)*` matches the whole word: http://ideone.com/6FtR7m.

Comment: @LajosVeres ok i will add another example. one sec

Comment: @Sam which programming language are you using ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
(\w)*

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w)*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «*»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w»
```

Will give you two matches:
**hello

world**

```
\w

Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w»
```

Will match every character (individually) on the sentence:

h
e
l
l
o
w
o
r
l
d

Comment: I didn't downvote. I'm confused by your first example though. When I run (\w)* I only get hello (not world). This is in Javascript.

Comment: use the `g modifier: global`. All matches (don't return on first match) - http://regex101.com/r/pS0hW1

Comment: `var myregexp = /(\w+)/g;`

Comment: Not sure, but they might have downvoted because the OP din't use the `g` flag in the question. The fact that it matches all the characters when using the `g` flag is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't mind about downvotes, as long as the come along with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Sam, the reason why (\w)* returns "s" in Group 1 against "delicious" is that there can only be one Group 1. Each time a new character is matched by (\w), the parentheses force the new value of the character to be captured into Group 1. "s" is the last character, so it is the final Group 1 reported to you by the engine.

If you wanted to capture the first letter into Group 1 instead, you could go with something like:

```
(\w)\w*
```

This causes the first character to be captured. There is no quantifier on the capturing parentheses, so Group 1 doesn't change. The remaining `\w*` optionally match any additional characters.

Also please note that when you run `(\w)*` against "hello world", the matches are not "hello" and "o" as you stated. The matches (if you match them all) are "hello" and "world". The Group 1 captures are "o" and "d", the last letters of each word.

Reference: [All about capture](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html)

Answer (score 0):

'*' matches the preceding part zero or more times and bind tightly to the element on the left. 
Example: m*o will match o, mo, mmo, mmmmo and so on.
Parentheses () are used to mark sub-expressions, also called capture groups.
So (\w)* is repeated capturing group.

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eT4vT4)

Answer (score 0):

Remember, a repeated capturing group always captures the last group.

So.

`(\w)*` on `hello` will check one character at a time unless it reaches the last match.
Thus will get `o` in the capture group.

`(\w)*` on `helloworld` will check one character at a time unless it reaches the last match.
Thus will get `d` in the capture group.

`(\w)*` on `hello123` will check one character at a time unless it reaches the last match.
Thus will get `3` in the capture group.

`(\w)*` on `helloworld@3w4` will check one character at a time unless it reaches the last match. Thus will get `d` in the capture group since `@` is not a valid `\w`ord character( only `[_0-9a-zA-Z]` allowed).

Answer (score -1):

`\w` is a RegEx shortcut for `[_a-zA-Z0-9]` which means any letter, digit, or an underscore.

When you add an asterisk `*` after anything, it means it can appear from 0 to unlimited times.

- If you want to match all the letters in your input, use `\w`
- If you want to match whole words in your input, use `\w+` (use `+` and not `*` since a word has at least one letter)

Also, when you're surrounding stuff in your RegEx with brackets, they become a capture group, which means they will appear in your results, which is why `(\w)*` is different from `(\w*)`

#### Useful RegEx sites:

- [**RegexPal**](http://regexpal.com/)
- [**Debuggex**](https://www.debuggex.com/)

Comment: almost, you missed the underscore `_` and digits `0-9`

Comment: Better to say "If you want to *match*..." (or maybe *consume*).  Save the word *capture* for describing what capturing groups do.  Also, the whole-word regex should be `\w+`, not `\w*`.